# SSRS Reading CDATA from Web Service

Tags: sql-server, xml, web-services, reporting-services, cdata

I need to read data from a 3rd party web service into an SSRS report.

SoapUI shows a response of

`<soapBody>
<ExecuteSQLResponse xmlns="http://www.aspentech.com/SQLplus.WebService/">
<ExecuteSQLResult>
<![CDATA[<NewDataSet><Table><tagname>sampleTag</tagname>...`

When using an element path of

```
<ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="true">ExecuteSQLResponse/ExecuteSQLResult/NewDataSet/Table</ElementPath>
```

SSRS query designer shows a single row with an "xmlns" and an "ExecuteSQLResult" field; ExecuteSQLResult holds the payload starting with `<NewDataSet><Table><tagname`

I'm at a loss as to how to drill deeper into the XML and extract the fields (such as "tagname") into fields that I can use within the report.

From my research I think the issue is with the payload being tagged as CDATA, which appears to unparseable by SSRS without a large amount of "external" coding.

Any pointers would be most welcome.